# Cassandra/Hadoop recurring attempt message

Tags: hadoop, datastax-enterprise

I see the following messages on the console after issuing a dump in Pig. I have previously loaded the data from a Cassandra table which has over 15 Million records into a pig relation.

I'm running a 5 node Hadoop cluster and all nodes are displaying the same message as below;

INFO 14:16:22,225 attempt_201310071219_0003_m_000001_0 NaN%
INFO 14:16:25,294 attempt_201310071219_0003_m_000001_0 NaN%
INFO 14:16:28,366 attempt_201310071219_0003_m_000001_0 NaN%
INFO 14:16:31,434 attempt_201310071219_0003_m_000001_0 NaN%

Could someone please shed some light on this?

And looking at the job details in the web browser, I can see that the number of map and reduce tasks are set to 1. I was under the impression that map and reduce tasks are split across the 5 nodes rather than having one node do all the work?

UPDATE:

I've run the test on one Hadoop node (5 millions items) as suggested and I'm still seeing the same messages after issuing the Dump in Pig...

INFO 15:55:15,448 JVM with ID: jvm_201310141552_0001_m_-2064359790 given task: attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000002_0
 INFO 15:55:20,395 attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000002_0 0.0% setup
 INFO 15:55:20,397 Task attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000002_0 is done.
 INFO 15:55:20,398 reported output size for attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000002_0  was -1
 INFO 15:55:20,398 addFreeSlot : current free slots : 1
 INFO 15:55:21,021 Task 'attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000002_0' has completed task_201310141552_0001_m_000002 successfully.
 INFO 15:55:21,031 Adding task (MAP) 'attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0' to tip task_201310141552_0001_m_000000, for tracker 'tracker_CassENT.eveng.local:/10.xxxxx:46522'
 INFO 15:55:21,033 Choosing data-local task task_201310141552_0001_m_000000
 INFO 15:55:21,035 LaunchTaskAction (registerTask): attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 task's state:UNASSIGNED
 INFO 15:55:21,035 Trying to launch : attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 which needs 1 slots
 INFO 15:55:21,035 Received KillTaskAction for task: attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000002_0
 INFO 15:55:21,036 In TaskLauncher, current free slots : 1 and trying to launch attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 which needs 1 slots
 INFO 15:55:21,036 About to purge task: attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000002_0
 INFO 15:55:21,037 Map ID attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000002_0 not found in cache
 INFO 15:55:21,050 No new JVM spawned for jobId/taskid: job_201310141552_0001/attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0. Attempting to reuse: jvm_201310141552_0001_m_-2064359790
 INFO 15:55:21,421 JVM with ID: jvm_201310141552_0001_m_-2064359790 given task: attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0
 INFO 15:55:24,865 GC for ParNew: 216 ms for 1 collections, 89930816 used; max is 3200253952
 INFO 15:55:27,708 attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 NaN% 
 INFO 15:55:30,759 attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 NaN% 
 INFO 15:55:33,801 attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 NaN% 
 INFO 15:55:36,860 attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 NaN% 
 INFO 15:55:39,940 attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 NaN% 
 INFO 15:55:42,989 attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 NaN% 
 INFO 15:55:46,043 attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 NaN% 
 INFO 15:55:49,836 attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 NaN% 
 INFO 15:55:52,874 attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 NaN% 
 INFO 15:55:55,913 attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 NaN% 
 INFO 15:55:58,958 attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 NaN% 
 INFO 15:56:02,068 attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 NaN% 
 INFO 15:56:05,128 attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 NaN% 
 INFO 15:56:08,184 attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 NaN% 
 INFO 15:56:11,243 attempt_201310141552_0001_m_000000_0 NaN%

Why is this happening?

Thanks
Majd

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something wrong with your cluster setting. Can you post your ring info? Can you test it on one node first, then move to multiple nodes testing.